# Perl adding line to begininning

Tags: perl

I have a perl script I am writing to parse a file based on regex. The problem is the file always starts with a new line. When I turn on hidden chars in vi it shows up as a "$" (this is vi on cygwin). is there a way I can use regex to remove them? I tried

> s/\n//g

But that did not seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure the newline character is `\n` and not `\r\n`?

Comment: are you matching against the entire file as a string?  if you're going a line at a time you could just skip blank lines.

Comment: Also, there are other potentially better tools than perl regular expressions for parsing files...like `sed`

Comment: in vi try    :,$g/^$/d

Comment: I am not convinced that your problem is an extra newline at the beginning of the file. I am also not sure what else it is, based on your hidden chars analysis. However, there is a way we can find out for sure. If you have `hexdump` available in your cygwin installation, then do hexdump *filename* | head -2 and let us know what you get as the output.

Comment: @elmugrat I confirmed it with the spec I know about carriage returns as well but the chars I am seeing do not show up the same as the '\n's in my comma delimited file. They just show up as $ when I show hidden chars in vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If indeed your problem is caused solely by the presence of one extra line at the top of your input file, and presuming you are using a typical loop like `while (<FILE>) { ... }`, then you can skip the first line of the input file by inserting this line at the very beginning within your loop:

```
next unless $. > 1;
```

Comment: I would like a little more info on what this is doing. is $. the size of the current string?

Comment: @Jackie Actually, `$.` is a special variable in Perl that references the line number of the input as it is read. Read about the details here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my @file = read_file('input.txt');
shift(@file);
foreach(@file){
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little more about what you are doing here? I am assuming it has something to do with the shift.

Comment: Yeah - if you read a file into an array, every line becomes an element. `shift` removes the first element from the array, in this case your blank line.

Comment: Does it achieve what you want?

Comment: This does work however, I am going to go with the other answer only because it doesn't import another object (Slurp) to accomplish this. Now this could be just my misunderstanding of Perl, however, that solution seems simpler.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this sort of thing, so use whatever you prefer. Of course there are easy ways to read a file into an array without using file::slurp...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is using `sed`

```
sed 1d
```

Comment: Not using this one because it uses another application outside of the perl application. Is there a major reason why using sed instead of perl would be preferable?